# "No appropriate prime between 1024 and 1024 is available" when connecting to VShell with JSch

Tags: java, ssh, jsch

I have written a client using JSch (via username password based logging).

The following are the relevant lines of code:-

```
sshSession = jsch.getSession(userName, host, 22);
sshSession.setConfig("PreferredAuthentications", "password");
sshSession.setPassword(loginInfo);
java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
sshSession.setConfig(config);
sshSession.connect();
```

Now while connecting with VShell Server I am getting the following error:-

```
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: SSH_MSG_DISCONNECT: 11 No appropriate prime between 1024 and 1024 is available.  en
at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.read(Session.java:987)
at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:323)
at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:183)
at com.informatica.isp.autoprovision.APSSHClient.<init>(APSSHClient.java:65)
at com.informatica.isp.autoprovision.APClient.createAPComputeNode(APClient.java:84)
at com.informatica.isp.autoprovision.test.AWSMockClientTest.test(AWSMockClientTest.java:34)
at com.informatica.isp.autoprovision.test.AWSMockClientTest.main(AWSMockClientTest.java:42)
```

When I try to connect with a CLI client like PuTTY or xshell with the VShell Server it works. Is there a setting I am missing somehow in JSch? I could not find anything like this in either VShell or JSch forums hence posted here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possibly a limitation of your version of the JSCH library which may not allow it to successfully perform key exchange with anything other than a 1024-bit prime.  Consider contacting JCraft to see if they have a version available that supports using larger primes for diffie-hellman group exchange.  If they don't, contact your VShell administrator and ask if they would be willing to modify the VShell 4.1.1+ primes.txt file to include 1024-bit prime numbers.

As a part of logjam [research](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2015/05/the_logjam_and_.html) there is a potential vulnerability in diffie-hellman group exchange when using 1024-bit and smaller primes.

From the VShell 4.1.1 [history file](https://www.vandyke.com/products/vshell/history.txt): "In light of a potential vulnerability with SSH key exchange, similar to the TLS Logjam vulnerability, the diffie-hellman group1 key-exchange algorithm is no longer enabled by default and all 1024 bit primes have been removed from VShell's primes.txt file."

Comment: That resolves the problem thanks. I got a new primes.txt from Vshell customer support for the same.

Comment: The JSch change log outlines that 0.1.53 has a fix for the 1024-bit prime limitation.  http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/ChangeLog

Answer (score 1):

Googling for the error message, I've found *(the link is dead now)*:

> This problem has been known to be caused by VShell having an empty primes.txt file and using diffie-hellman group exchange.
>
> As a workaround for your SecureFX client, can you move diffie-hellman to the top of the list in Session Options / Connection / SSH2 / Key exchange to see if you're able to get past the error?

Check for the `primes.txt` on the server.

Or try to select another key exchange algorithm using

```
config.put("kex", <preference list>);
```

Comment: But you are not using regular OpenSSH sshd, right? This is VShell. What KEX does PuTTY use?